# How can I put \" in a string quoted with "?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a certain string from a file which I cannot change. When I read the string into the python code it causes problem cause there is \" in the string. I just dont want this.

I have a string like this :

```
"abcabc"
```

I want to make it like this:

```
"abc\"abc"
```

I cannot change the quotes of the string to ''' or '.

Comment: `\"` will insert a quote. `\\ ` will insert a backslash. To insert both, `\\\"`.

Comment: How come you can change the content of the string but not how it's delimited?

Comment: I have a certain string from a file which I cannot change. When I read the string into the python code it causes problem cause there is \" in the string. I just dont want this.

Comment: Then you *don't* *"have a string like"* `"abcabc"`, you have a different string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
s = "abcabc"
print  (s[:s.index('c')+1] + "\\\"" + s[s.index('c')+1:]) # abc\"abc
```

> **Escape Sequences** Escape Sequences are set of special characters used to print characters which can’t be typed directly using keyboard.
>   Each Escape Sequence starts with a backslash ( `\` ) character.

```
print ("\\") # \
print ("\"") # "
print ("\\\"") # \"
```